# How to restart apache server through cygwin and ssh

Tags: apache, cygwin

The scenario is this: I have an Apache web server installed on a Windows 7 machine. The same machine has cygwin installed, and cygwin is configured with ssh. This allows me to ssh into cygwin remotely, and then, through cygwin, I can access other files on this computer (even those not in cygdrive).

My question: How can I restart the web server through cygwin if I am accessing it remotely through ssh? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: yes, just find and execute the `apachectl` program that should be in the apache binaries directory.  `apachectl restart` is I think the exact command line you need (it's been a while, not 100% sure)

Comment: There is no apachectl or apache2ctl in my bin directory... Do you know how to find this file?

Comment: It's normally part of the Apache distribution, but maybe they solve process control management differently under Windows.  If you installed Apache as a service (which is quite likely) `net stop xxx` followed by `net start xxx` where xxx is the name of the Apache service should probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service is called `Apache`, then like this:

```
ssh machine "net stop Apache; net start Apache"
```

Sometimes it is called `Apache2` or `httpd`, depending on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

In linux is

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
or
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc
and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#wincons

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$ service httpd restart
```

or

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```